# Rest git changes files before push to remote origin?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-push

I want to reset changes of specific files before the push to the remote origin and after pushed successfully all changes come back to files, also I don't want to use `.gitignore` because I need these files to be in tracking by git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to temporarily 'ignore' changes to those files in your working directory using:

> git update-index
>
> --[no-]assume-unchanged
>
> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[git-update-index --no-assume-unchanged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged)

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file.txt
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file.txt
git ls-files -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you are doing some changes which are not finished yet,
but also you want to commit to that repo.

> `git stash` comes to rescue you.

for more info, check out https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash.